# how to generate automatic transaction code with Laravel 7 with format : [code-date-sequence] LIKE: PSN-22102021-001

Tags: php, transactions, unique, laravel-7, unique-key

I want to generate a unique transaction code with using date an example: PSN-22102021-001 or PSN-22102021001, how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: not yet, because I do not understand.

Comment: help me...i'm still learning laravel, so i don't know how to generate automatic transaction code with laravel

Answer (score 0):

OK, not sure what database you are using, so will keep this in band.
I will assume the PSN is relevant to all codes, as you give no idea what this is.
Next, you will find generating unique IDs very difficult, and long, unless they are incremental in some way.

In PHP, you have two options (there are others, but I will let others fill those gaps). microtime(), or uniqid().

If you are using microtime(), you could use the following:

```
<?php

echo makeID();

function makeID($prefix = 'PRN'){
        $time = str_replace('.', '-', microtime(true) );
        return $prefix.'-'.$time;
}
```

This would return a number like: **PRN-1634871496-0619**
However, there is a very small possibility that two times are generated in the same microsecond, and this fails.

To ensure a unique ID, you would need to generate alpha-numeric options such as this..

```
<?php

echo makeUniqueId();

function makeUniqueId($prefix='PRN'){
        return $prefix.'-'.uniqid();
}
```

This would return something like **PRN-617229f798988**

Comment: I use mysql as the database, and the ID auto-increment, the PSN code is the starting code for all transaction codes, here the transaction number format is: [PSN-today- increasing serial number], PSN-22102021-001

here, the transaction code I made separately from the ID.

Comment: you're right, PSN relevant to all code